# Is it possible to reduce the angle of fully extended flaps of an aircraft without affecting lift generated?

Tags: aircraft-design, flaps

I think flaps are inspired from eagle feathers which increase the overall wing surface area and help provide the necessary lift at lower speeds. However, fully extended flaps hang lower and cause more fuel to be burnt (might be because they interact and reduce the exhaust thrust and create more drag). Are the current wing flaps fully optimized or is there any possibility of improvement?

Lowering fuel consumption while maintaining same lift and safety of aircraft by possible geometrical modification is good, because it helps reduce the carbon emissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rest assured that current flap configurations used in modern aircraft are fully optimized.

Developing new aircraft, and operating them is a multi billion dollar enterprize, and although it would be foolish to claim that design choises are not compromises to some extent, it is certain that no stone is left unturned when aerodynamics of the wing is being designed.

Current solutions are the best that can be achieved with present day materials and budget, not to forget the reliability of the solution.

There are known solutions such as blown flaps, boundary layer suction and so on and so forth, but they all have downsides that make them not utilizable in large scales.

To adress the point of fuel consumption: the current flap configurations are designed to maximize fuel efficiency. Flaps are being used in portions of flight that last for relatively short periods (say, 15 minutes max. for intermediate flap settings, a couple of minutes for full flaps). By utilizing high lift and thus high drag flaps for landing, the wing can otherwise be designed to be very, very efficient for the main part of the flight.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to reduce the angle of fully extended flaps

**Yes**.  Fully extended flaps are only used for landing.  They allow for a lower landing speeds and more drag, resulting in a shorter roll-out.

For less drag, they can be reduced, or with higher speeds, fully retracted.

With aircraft, lift increases with the *square* of speed, which is why flaps are generally used only when the aircraft is flying at a slower speed.

Best *distance per unit fuel burned* is near the lowest drag configuration.
Weight is critical too.  The best bet for fuel efficiency is to have *one* wing that is properly sized for the weight and speed desired.

Adding flaps is essentially adding another wing for slower flight.  It works, just not (aerodynamicly) as well.

Comment: I’m curious, why did you omit and not answer “without affecting the lift generated?” Did you think this part was irrelevant?  Because it’s really the central point of the whole question.

Comment: Might be because the idea that flaps "affect... the lift generated" is the wrong way to think about them. Many factors go into the generation of Lift. Changing the lift is not the point of flaps. The point is to lower the minimum speed at which wing can still generate sufficient lift to maintain 1 G flight.  In actuality, deploying flaps *lowers* the maximum available lift at most (cruise and higher) airspeeds because it lowers the wings maximum allowable structural load limit.

Comment: Good points.  Going by the flaps 0, 10, 20, 30 degrees, 10 increases lift coefficient, 20 and especially 30 mainly add drag.  With flaps, *the rest of the wing has to stay lower AoA to keep the flaps portion from stalling* (what Charles pointed out).  When airliners drop full flaps, they have Snoopy, the Red Baron, and the whole Flying Circus going on back there.

Comment: @CharlesBretana "The point is to lower the minimum speed at which wing can still generate sufficient lift to maintain 1 G flight." And the flaps do this by... (sheepishly from the back row) "by changing the lift sir?" "NO!" (sharp smacking sound...)

Comment: @CharlesBretana - re "Changing the lift is not the point of flaps." - but changing the lift *coefficient* is.  Re "In actuality, deploying flaps lowers the maximum available lift at most (cruise and higher) airspeeds because it lowers the wings maximum allowable structural load limit." - seems odd, as the flaps would appear to cause the inboard portions of the wings to generate most of the lift, reducing bending loads.  Do you have a source for this?  Maybe should be a new ASE question--

Comment: Re "With flaps, the rest of the wing has to stay lower AoA to keep the flaps portion from stalling (what Charles pointed out). " - are you sure?  I can understand a claim that the AoA of wing as whole must decrease when flaps are deployed *to keep the  net lift force constant at 1 G*, but this is different from a claim that deploying flaps while holding AoA of unflapped portions of wing constant will create a *stall*.

Comment: @quietFlyer, yes, almost every aircraft I have flown has had a lower structural limit when flaps were down than when the wing was clean. In the F-4, as I recall, the structural limit was 8.5 Gs clean (up to 37,500 lbs), but with flaps out it was only 4Gs . In Cessna 340 it was 3.8 vs 2.0. Cessna 172, 3.8 vs 3.0, I could go on & on. Why?, because flaps are not built sturdy enough to handle the load they would need to manage at those higher g-loads. They are for flying *Slow*, during approach and landing. If you extended flaps at maneuvering speed, and tried to turn hard, the flaps would rip off

Comment: Secondly, to the comment about lift coefficient, it is not the *increase* in the lift coefficient that is important, it is the *shifting* of the lift coefficient curve to the left (to a lower airspeed range), that is the point. This shift allows the aircraft to maintain 1 G flight (at or near the maximum lift coefficient), at a lower airspeed.  *THAT* is the point.

Comment: (Somehow "lift coefficient" is a combination of a particular airfoil *and* AoA.  So for a given speed, adding more camber allows for lower AoA to generate 1G *or* allows the *same* Aoa for a lower speed.  Slats add camber too).  More preaching to the choir.  Ha!

Comment: @Robert, My comment about extending flaps at cruise was made simply to explain why flaps are not designed to withstand the forces they would experience then ... i.e. why the design load factor is lower with flaps extended than it is when they are retracted.

Comment: But the shifting of the lift coefficient curve to the left, (to a lower airspeed range), is EXACTLY the point of flaps. It most certainly IS a "good idea" to land at the slowest possible safe airspeed that you can. That is the same thing as the "at or near the maximum *safe* lift coefficient". And shifting the lift coefficient curve to the left is what allows an aircraft to land at lower speeds. Am I contradicting you? I'm not entirely sure if your comment is intended to agree or disagree with my earlier statement, which I entered in response to @Michael Hall, not to your correct answer.

Comment: @CharlesBretana thanks for clearing that all up.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!